# Host website and run in Browser, without running it via IIS

Tags: iis, windows-8, hosting

How can I run an .htm **without** using IIS in the browser in Win8?

don't ask me why I want to do this, just please help me answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Open up your favorite browser, choose File | Open, point to your .HTM file, and load it.

NOTE: In Windows 8 there are two different browsers - the "metro" browser that is on the new desktop and regular IE that runs on the Windows desktop.  The above will probably only work in the regular IE browser.